# Is there any dimens.xml with standart dimensions?

Tags: android, screen, dpi

I want to know if is there some web or something with examples of dimens.xml files to support multiple screen sizes?

Comment: You have to provide different dimens.xml files in different values-xy folders

Comment: Yes, I know. But, what I asking is for dimens.xml examples. If I make an icon for my S3 (720x1280 - 320dpi) with 150dpx150dp, those dimensions didn't fit for example in a S2 (480x800 - 217dpi). What I want to know is a way to calculate, to convert the dimensions in dimen.xml in another resolution.

Comment: If you use dp instead of px, everything should scale fairly well. Please note that API Level 11 introdices a padding of 16 dp and API Level 14 introduces a padding of 32 dp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can make folders of values for in which different dimens values are stored for multiple screen resolutions: 
 for example you can make folder in **res** named, **values-720x1280**,   **values-320x480**,  **values-240x320** and put dimens.xml in each folder with different values in it...

you can define custom height with dimens(Suppose for 720X1280 device) like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <dimen name="icon_width">55dip</dimen>
        <dimen name="icon_height">55dip</dimen>
        <dimen name="photo_width">170dip</dimen>
        <dimen name="photo_height">155dip</dimen>
    </resources>

and for values-320x480 dimens.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="icon_width">20dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="icon_height">20dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="photo_width">100dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="photo_height">100dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then reference them in your other xml:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height">
```

try it now and tell your experience

From HoneyComb, there is a new way to fix all of this. Your resources folder should now look like this:

[image: try this]

Comment: What I mean is if is there a way to calculate (create) others dimens.xml automatically or something. I have a large dimens.xml and I need to create the rest of the resolutions ldpi, mdpi, etc. Is there a tool for that?

Comment: I've just see your edited post. For example, icon_width is 55dip and 20dip. How do you know that this is the correct dimens to fit a 320x480 screen?

Comment: Are you looking for the scale factor? ldpi = 0.75, mdpi = 1.0, hdpi = 1.5, xhdpi = 2.0, xxhdpi = 3.0, xxxhdpi = 4.0

Comment: when you create folders like what i said then android will autometically detect near resolutions and exact resolutions for device and set value from perticular dimens.

Answer (score 0):

Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes and densities. For applications, the Android system provides a consistent development environment across devices and handles most of the work to adjust each application's user interface to the screen on which it is displayed. At the same time, the system provides APIs that allow you to control your application's UI for specific screen sizes and densities, in order to optimize your UI design for different screen configurations. For example, you might want a UI for tablets that's different from the UI for handsets.

Although the system performs scaling and resizing to make your application work on different screens, you should make the effort to optimize your application for different screen sizes and densities. In doing so, you maximize the user experience for all devices and your users believe that your application was actually designed for their devices—rather than simply stretched to fit the screen on their devices.

Follow [This Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)